# Problems with finding limit of $\frac{1}{e^n/n^n - 2(n!)/n^n} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I have the sequence $$\dfrac{1}{e^n/n^n - 2(n!)/n^n}$$ and by looking at the sequence for $n$ going towards infinity I concluded that the sequence diverges and that it's limit is $ -\infty$. I got to this result by looking at the limit for $e^n/n^n$ and $n!/n^n $ which both go toward zero as n goes to infinity. However $e^n/n^n$ approaches zero faster than $n!/n^n$ thus we get that the denominator ($e^n/n^n - 2n!/n^n $) goes to zero but it is approaching from the negative side? I am not sure if I have solved  it correctly? Is there another way to state this?

Comment: Is it (2n)! or 2(n!)  ?

Comment: Oh sorry it is 2 (n!), I wrote it fast so there are some errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+1%2F%28e%5En%2Fn%5En-2n%21%2Fn%5En%29+as+n-%3Einf

You are right, the denominator is approaching $0$ from the negative side because $e^n/n^n<2n!/n^n$ and both go to $0$.

$(e*e*e*...*e<1*2*3*..*n$ for $n>5$; you can prove that saying $e^6<404$ and $6!=720$, from that point onwards, for any e added to the product, a larger number, over 7, is added to the right side). I wanted to post this as a comment but I don't have enough reputation

Answer (score 1):

Write instead $$\frac {n^n} {e^n - 2 (n!)}.$$

Using Stirling's approximation, we have $$\frac {n^n} {e^n - 2 (n!)} = \frac {e^n} {(e^2/n)^n - 2 \sqrt {2 \pi n} (1 + o (1))} \to -\frac {e^n} {2 \sqrt {2 \pi n} (1 + o (1))} \to - \infty.$$